# How to reverse the image sequence of a movie clip in video editor ?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I opened the layout for video editing in Blender, added a movie clip onto one channel and made two hard cuts. How do I continue from here in order to reverse the sequence of images of the movie clip part between the hard cuts ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enable the backwards checkbox as indicated in the image below.

[image]

Comment: It's now called "Reverse".